# C++: problem with while loop for large number of iterations (code is attached)

Tags: c++

First of all, thank you all for helping me with my questions before.

Input 1:  (CSV file) listdata (input as list of vectors)

```
0,44,38,42,29,26,29,18,39,29,25,18,15,18,34,31,22,12,14,22,9,27
0,0,43,37,32,30,24,25,29,16,24,30,29,9,26,8,24,8,7,12,13,15
0,0,0,21,31,32,24,21,26,23,25,23,21,18,18,19,21,11,17,11,12,10
0,0,0,0,23,27,28,24,26,20,13,19,23,22,20,16,18,11,6,12,10,7
0,0,0,0,0,17,31,26,25,24,30,25,25,15,19,8,19,13,7,16,7,4
0,0,0,0,0,0,18,22,21,31,13,30,18,15,19,14,15,13,10,9,8,7
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,20,17,28,25,13,18,8,18,23,11,9,19,6,7
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,12,24,11,25,15,16,12,16,17,4,9,7,8
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,21,25,7,23,23,27,20,15,22,8,9,7,10
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,18,21,14,14,10,19,14,9,5,11,7,3
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,25,5,15,16,19,15,8,10,12,3,11
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,16,9,12,16,8,13,10,5,5
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,29,10,10,7,16,5,6,7,9
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,22,13,6,10,2,6,13,11
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,22,13,9,7,11,7,9
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,15,12,20,8,13
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,4,11,5,10
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,11,9,3
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,8
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,10
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

input 2 : listmoves 14630x8 entries (CSV file).

```
{here is couple of lines from the file:
 1,2,3,4,-1,-3,-2,-4
 1,2,3,5,-1,-3,-2,-5
 1,2,3,6,-1,-3,-2,-6
 1,2,3,7,-1,-3,-2,-7
 1,2,3,8,-1,-3,-2,-8
 1,2,3,9,-1,-3,-2,-9
 1,2,3,10,-1,-3,-2,-10
 1,2,3,11,-1,-3,-2,-11 }
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

/*reading data files into vectors (22x22 matrix is in CSV format and 14630x8 vectors of moves in CSV format)*/
void readListData(vector< vector<short> > &vvec, const char *filename) {

    ifstream dataFile;

    dataFile.open(filename);
    if(!dataFile.good()) {
        cerr << "Could not open file '" << filename << "' for read\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    string line;

    while (getline(dataFile, line)) {

        istringstream iss(line);
        vector<short> lvec;
        while (!iss.eof()) {
            short num;
            iss >> num;
            lvec.push_back(num);
            char ch;
            iss >> ch;
        }
        vvec.push_back(lvec);
    }
}

/* write modified list of vectors into file at the end */
void writeListData(vector< vector <short> > &vvec, std::string filename) {
    ofstream dataOutFile;

    dataOutFile.open(filename.c_str());
    if(!dataOutFile.good()) {
        cerr << "Could not open file 'listdata.out' for write\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (vector<vector <short> >::size_type i = 0; i < vvec.size(); i++) {
        vector<short>::size_type j;
        for (j = 0; j < vvec[i].size() - 1; j++) {
            dataOutFile << vvec[i][j] << ",";
        }
        dataOutFile << vvec[i][j] << endl;
    }
    dataOutFile.flush();
}

/* creat a toy vector for the input */
void copyVectors(const vector<vector<short> >& source, vector<vector<short> >& dest){
    for(unsigned int i=0; i< source.size(); i++){
        vector<short> rowSrc = source[i];
        vector<short> rowDest;
        for(unsigned int j=0; j< rowSrc.size(); j++){
            rowDest.push_back(rowSrc[j]);
            }

        dest.push_back(rowDest);
        }   
} 



int main() {

    vector<vector <short> > mvec; //moves vectors
    vector<vector <short> > vvecOrig; // original data vectors

    readListData(vvecOrig, "listdata");
    readListData(mvec, "listmoves");
    const int NITERATIONS = 25; //set number of iterations
    int numTables=25; //set number of outputs 

    vector<vector <short> > vvec;
    copyVectors(vvecOrig, vvec);

    for (int i=0; i<numTables; i++) {

        srand((int) time(NULL)); 

       int j = 0;
       while (j < NITERATIONS) {

        int movesIndex = rand() % mvec.size(); //generate random # from 0 to 14630 


        short a = mvec[movesIndex][0]; 
        short b = mvec[movesIndex][1];
        short c = mvec[movesIndex][2];
        short d = mvec[movesIndex][3];
        short e = abs(mvec[movesIndex][4]);
        short f = abs(mvec[movesIndex][5]);
        short g = abs(mvec[movesIndex][6]);
        short h = abs(mvec[movesIndex][7]);



        int x=vvec[e - 1][f - 1]-1;
        int y=vvec[g - 1][h - 1]-1;
        int z=vvec[a - 1][b - 1]+1;
        int w=vvec[c - 1][d - 1]+1;
        int x1=vvec[e - 1][f - 1];
        int y1=vvec[g - 1][h - 1];
        int z1=vvec[a - 1][b - 1];
        int w1=vvec[c - 1][d - 1];

            /*check for probability of the move */
           /*if move does not create negative number in the list of vectors*/
        if ((x>=0 && y>=0)) {


            if  (x==0 ){
                 x=1;
            }
            if(y==0){
                y=1;
            }
            if (z==0){
                z=1;
            }
            if (w==0){
                w=1;
            }
            if (x1==0){
                x1=1;
            }
            if (y1==0){
                y1=1;
            }
            if (z1==0){
                z1=1;
            }
            if (w1==0){
                w1=1;
            }
        int numerator=x*y;  
        int denominator=z1*w1;


        double probMove=numerator/denominator; //conditional probability
        double prob = rand() % RAND_MAX; //generate random numer [0,1]  

        if ( probMove >=1 || probMove>prob) {
        /*make a move if conditions are satisfied */

                vvec[a - 1][b - 1]++;
                vvec[c - 1][d - 1]++;
                vvec[e - 1][f - 1]--;
                vvec[g - 1][h - 1]--;
            j++;

            }
        }
        }
    /*write output file after iterations*/
    std::stringstream filenamestr;
    filenamestr<<"listdata."<<i<<".out"; 
    writeListData(vvec, filenamestr.str());

     }
    return 0;
}
```

The programs runs and produces desirable output. However, when I change number of iteration in `while` loop to about 1000, and then run the program in the command line, it seems to be stuck in the loop ( doesn't produce any output and then terminal (on mac) becomes unresponsive). I am even scared to set it to 30,000 which is what my simulation required.

I am very new to C++ and I am not sure how to troubleshoot this.

Please help!

**UPDATE:** I changed the following lines:

```
srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));
...
double probMove=double(numerator)/denominator; 
double prob = double(rand() )/ (RAND_MAX);
```

well, I cout `prob`, and it seems now that when `prob` is less than 10^(-5) the script becomes unresponsive. I have no idea how to approach this...

Comment: Where does it enter the infinite loop? I assume in the while loop, but how do you know? What have you done to debug it?

Comment: @Falmarri it definitely enters the infinite loop within `while` loop. I tried to put different print out statement at different locations within the `while` loop. Moreover, if while loop is executed I will get a file output, which I don't get if number of iterations more than 200.

Comment: 1) Something that looks strange is that you're using values of `a1` and `b1` but you're never assigning to them, were they `x1` and `y1` before?  2) There seems to be a chance that you run out of non-negative values in `vvec` because of the updates inside `if(probMove >=1 || probMove>prob)`

Comment: Sorry, I have not corrected those, but did in my program...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll tell you 2 things:

- probMove is an integer, even though you are saving it in a double variable.  When two integers are divided together, the result is always an integer.  When at least one of the operands is a double then the result is a double. Fix this by making either num or den a double.
- `rand()%RAND_MAX` is probably not doing what you intend (you want it to be a number between 0 and 1 it seems).  rand() is a value between 0 and 32767, and RAND_MAX is 32767.  So you're basically going to get the value of rand() back (number between 0 and 32766) unless rand() happened to return 32767, in which case you'll get a 0.

Comment: First, @bobobobo, Thank you for your comments. 


(1) in my case denominator and numerator are both product of 2 integers. Can I assign them as double?


(2) I corrected that line to `double prob = double(rand()) / (RAND_MAX+1);`

Now, I tried running the script again, now with 1000 iterations, and it crashes....

Comment: 1) Yes, you can assign them as double.  2) If its crashing, then there may be a problem with your data.  Check that your assignments a,b,c,d, x,y,z,w that every array access is within bounds of the array.

Comment: I finished the program! you comments made a big difference :) thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are probably hitting a case where `probMove` is either zero, very close to zero, or even negative, in which case `j++` will never execute to increment your loop.

Comment: but the if this is the case, I thought my program just returns to the beginning of the loop... there are 14630 choices in the listmoves file.

Comment: I agree, it looks like he is using `size_type` in some places, but I do see an int in a loop. Loop counters should always be `size_t` or at least an unsigned type. Even better, use iterators wherever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Also,

```
double prob = rand() % RAND_MAX; //generate random numer [0,1]
```

doesn't do what the comment says. If that's what you want, you need

```
double prob = double(rand()) / RAND_MAX;
```

Comment: That would generate `prob` in `[0,1)`

Comment: I changed it to `double prob = double(rand()) / (RAND_MAX+1);` and still it generates 1 or 2 tables and then crashes....

Comment: If `mvec` is filled with data from listmoves, the values for `e` through `h` are negative, but then you use them as indices, which is probably not what you want. Do negatives have a special meaning? Like "taken backwards from the end of the list"?

Comment: I just take absolute value of negatives and they point to the values in listdata (vector index, and value index). The probability is computed using valus from listdata, which are nonnegative.

Comment: I figured out that I have to take for `srand((unsigned int) time(NULL))`, but when the prob is too small the script seems to crash... I don't know how to go around this....